# Can transactional applications (like e commerce/ money transfer etc) be built on no sql db

Tags: mysql, nosql, transactional

So I want to know whether transaction based web applications can have no sql databases instead of my sql. Or is there a rule of thumb to use My sql, taking into care for standard compliance?

Comment: Does your storage guarantee ACID?

Comment: Are you talking tabout 'NoSQL' technology?

Comment: @zerkms..is there a service available to test that?

Comment: @LolCoder yes nosql like mongodb.

Comment: @Minty: not service, but I'm sure documentation should state that. And mongodb isn't ACID-compilant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence of the OP (`...transaction based web applications...`) in some sense answers the question.  You would need a NoSQL implementation that does support transactions so that you can guarantee atomic updates across multiple data entries.  A response to a comment seems to indicate that  MongoDB is the DB under consideration.  That [does not seem to be a good choice for transactions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-do-transactions-and-locking-in-mongodb).

Unless there were some kind of add-on that provided ACID transaction support, then it would make some operations difficult.  The obvious and overused example is debiting from one account and crediting another.  If that couldn't be done in a single transaction, then you would quite possibly be losing money (or creating money if you did the credit first ;).

I don't know about "rules of thumb" for this question, but my suspicion is that you would find an easier time of it using a "traditional" database for a commerce-based system.